# Random date-time between two date-times in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, datetime

How can I get a random date-time between two date-times in Excel VBA?

I tried

```
worksheetFunction.Randbetween(time1, time2)
```

but that only delivers the date without hours, minutes and seconds (although `time1` and `time2` are including hours, minutes and seconds)

I also tried the following code where I declared tmp as string.

```
tmp = DateDiff("s", time1, time2) [to get the seconds]
tmp = Int((tmp +1) * Rnd) [to get a random number inbetween the DateDiff]
tmp = tmp + CDbl(time1)
```

But that also doesn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
worksheetFunction.Randbetween(time1, time2) + Rnd()
```

Rnd() will generate a value between 0 and 1, and time is stored as a fraction of a day

You can also avoid the first part and use

```
time1+Rnd()*(time2-time1+1)
```

Remove `+1` if you want time2 '00:00:00' to be the upper limit, or if both `time1` and `time2` are datetimes, not dates

You should also use `Randomize` statement before using both versions.